# Does changing Firestore or Cloud Storage security rules require an app update?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage, firebase-security

i have this rule here

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 6, 21);
    }
  }
}
```

i literally only want to change the timestamp.date so it looks like this

```js
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 7, 15);
    }
  }
}
```

the thing is, i have a backend deployed on google cloud using this database, would my app be affected in anyway if i just change the timestamp.date here? would i need to redeploy for the change to occur or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

To make a change to your security rules you don't need to make any changes to your application itself. You just write or upload the new rules, and they'll take effect on the server immediately.

---

Of course if your new security rules are more restrictive than the old ones, you may need to update your application code to meet the requirements of those more restrictive rules. Moving the date further into the future does not make the rules more restrictive though, so there won't be a need for that here.